# xsd DataSet switch to Oracle.DataAccess.Client driver

Tags: oracle, xsd, obsolete

I'm currently upgrading an old application to the .Net 4.6.1 framework.  I'm fixing all warnings about System.Data.OracleClient being obsolete by updating everything to use the Oracle.DataAccess.Client driver.

Everything is going well, but there are several xsd DataSets that are tied to the older driver.  The code behind for the designer view warns that the code is auto-generated so don't touch it.

I've looked at the Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2015, but there doesn't seem to be a clean way to transition these files.

Does anyone out there have any experience with this?  Is there a straight forward method for converting the files to the Oracle driver, or should I recreate the xsd files using the Oracle tools?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't currently a good way to do this.  Since the System.Data.OracleClient is still available, it is best to continue using the obsolete driver and test before doing any upgrades.